# performing multiple pairwise comparisons against a single control with ggstatsplot

Tags: r, data-visualization

In my dataset I have a single negative control and then numerous groups that are treated with a compound in increasing doses. I have figured out how to automate running ggbetweenstats on my large list of these treatments.

```
library(Rmpfr)
library(ggstatsplot)

 ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
          data = data, 
          x = treatment, 
          y = value,
          messages = FALSE )
```

However, the ggbetweenstats method compares every single group against every other group and adjust accordingly for multiple hypothesis testing. However, in my case I only would like to compare each treatment against the untreated control (with and without multiple hypothesis testing).

Is there a way to use one group as the single baseline against which automatically all other treatments are measured? Or do I need to implement this in a separate loop/function? I would prefer to run this in ggstatsplot since it would generate a convenient set of plots that are easy to scroll through.

EDIT: It is unclear to me if 'Cross Validated' or 'Stack Overflow' is the better place to ask.

Comment: As this question is fundamentally about statistical practice rather than programming per se, this is the correct place to post. If you cross-posted this question on Stack Overflow, please remove from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard test for comparing multiple treatments against a single control is [Dunnett's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test). [This page](https://www.statology.org/dunnetts-test-r/) shows an example of how to implement that test in R with the [`DescTools` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DescTools).

In your situation, however, that test will throw away the quantitative dose-response characteristics of your study. Your study might be better served by using an analysis designed for dose-response studies, like that provided by the R [`drc` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drc).